# Count unique distinct values if condition is true

Tags: excel, count, unique

I try to count the unique values in list but they have to fulfill the condition I have set.

```
{=SUM(IF($A$1:$A$25=$D$2; 1/COUNTIF($B$1:$B$25; $B$1:$B$25); 0))}
```

[image: excel count unique values]

There the first 25 rows of the **[`data`](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=bNtmiuV1)** as example.

How to count unique distinct values if condition is true in Excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just will posting the question, I [found](http://www.get-digital-help.com/2011/07/12/count-unique-distinct-values-that-meet-multiple-criteria-in-excel/) the answer:

```
{=SUM(IF($D$1=$A$1:$D$25, 1/(COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$25; $D$2; $B$1:$E$25; $B$1:$B$25)); 0))}
```

[image: correct anwser]